# Modify top frame with javascript, crossdomain?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i would like to have a frame on a page with a script that shows a modal in the parent-frame.
the problem is that the pages is on 2 different domains, and it seems that the browsers does not allow this when doing this crossdomain.

Is there any way to go around this so it works?
And which browsers would this work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible solutions:
http://www.cakemail.com/blog/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, and I'm pretty sure that it is not possible since they're from different domains, for « security reasons ».

Also, some browsers (like Google Chrome) don't do simple modals (you can click behind the modal without a problem) using the showModalDialog method.

We don't really know your situation so I can't think of a workaround.
I wish you the best of luck!